# How is the relation betwoon top quark and dark matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there any connection between dark matter and top quark.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: we don't know a lot about dark matter. so anything is possible. on the other hand, my friend if you know the universe is working based on 3 unknown phenomena, " DARK MATTER " , " DARK ENERGY "," DARK FLOW ", So let don't think that we know everything completely.

Comment: I don't think anyone is suggesting that we know everything.  On the other hand, it doesn't seem like you have — for example — read the wikipedia pages on the [top quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_quark) and [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter).  If you had, you either wouldn't have bothered asking this question, or would have had something more to say about it.  For example, what's so special about the top quark as opposed to any other quark?  How does it interact with other particles?  How does dark matter interact with other particles?  Why would they be related?

Comment: Billions of years ago they were close friends. But, the top quark stole some of dark matter's lunch money, and ever since they haven't talked. Now they hang out in completely different cliques, and dark matter will have nothing to do with any of the quarks.

Comment: The answer is maybe. If you google, you can find many theories in which there is a connection. But in most theories of dark matter, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Dark matter is generally considered to only interact through gravitational and perhaps weak nuclear interactions. As all quarks interact both with electromagnetism and the strong force, the answer is no.

Comment: Quarks interact weakly too (and, presumably, also gravitationally).

Comment: Aye, but as I interpret the question (I might be mistaken there...) it seems to be implying that dark matter might be composed of top quarks, which is what I meant to refute.

Comment: Ah, in that sense, you're answer is correct: as quarks interact strongly and electromagnetically, they cannot compose dark matter. I agree with that.

Comment: Also top quarks decay practically instantly, while dark matter has been around for billions of years.